# Garbage collector hangs OpenGL on HTC Ev-es

Tags: android, opengl-es, garbage-collection

I've been battling a hang (deadlock) in OpenGL for the past week.  I've finally realized that the system hangs after the garbage collector runs.  Here is an example from LogCat:

```
02-16 08:49:32.609: INFO/ActivityManager(98): Displayed activity com.southernstars.skysafari/.SkySafariActivity: 2219 ms (total 2219 ms)
02-16 08:49:37.369: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1863): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4144 objects / 387544 bytes in 46ms
02-16 08:49:37.389: ERROR/Adreno200-ES20(1863): gsl_device_waittimestamp failed in rb_timestamp_wait_on_timestamp
02-16 08:49:38.516: WARN/SharedBufferStack(1863): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=157, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
```

Anytime the LogCat shows a GC_FOR_MALLOC or a GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC, the app hangs with OpenGL in this LockCondition.  It appears that GC_EXPLICT, for the most part, does not cause a problem (maybe these are smaller allocs, I don't know).

Searching the internet, it seems that people are reporting things like this on the HTC phones.  Usually they say the problem is very sporadic and hard to reproduce.  I can reproduce it easily by simply putting a System.gc() call into my application flow or by doing something that allocates a chunk of memory forcing the GC to run.

I have this problem on an HTC Evo.  My development partner has a different phone and is not seeing this.

I'm totally at a loss what to do next.  Has anyone seen anything like this or have a plausible explanation for what is going on?  Is there any way it could be something unusual we are doing in the app?  Or is it just a bug in the HTC system or drivers?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: Did we miss something?

Comment: Well, not to be snide, but on all the questions I've asked so far, I've not gotten a single satisfactory response that actually solves the problem.  I'd be happy to accept an answer if there was one that answered the problem.  Would you like to be first?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: I looked at his (her?) questions (only 6 of them) and I agree with him (her) that there aren't and viable answers. I hardly think it's working 'against' the community if you don't accept answers that don't solve your problem...

Comment: I looked into two questions: one was answered by yourself (so just accept your own answer) and one was answered and but the guy also asked for more information, which you didn't provide...

Comment: Thanks for the verification that I'm not just taking without giving.  And by the way, I'm a guy.  I do have one more possible piece of info.  I have a large number of native methods called via JNI (maybe 120).  I do not register them because they use the standard format and apparently can be "discovered".  I'm wondering if I should be registering them?  Could registering the methods affect the way the GC runs while in native code?  The native methods are called on both the main thread and the OpenGL thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *finally* tracked down what is happening.  We are reading assets out of the APK using straight C code.  I had written a routine based upon some code on the net that would return a file descriptor and offset to the resource we needed to read.  The original code would dup() the fd before returning it.  I couldn't figure out why the dup() was needed.  The fd seemed to increment anyway as if it were already duped.  Anyway I had commented the dup out and left a comment that I didn't see it was necessary.

Turns out it is necessary.  It appears that somewhere in the file system code some sort of memory corruption was happening that was causing out OpenGL hangs.  When I restored the dup() everything started working again.